# How to make neural network with both of regression and classification outputs?

Tags: keras

I already trained a CNN for steering angle prediction with regression output. Also I trained CNN for classification (Two classes: road, no road). But I want to combine it. How to do it? Train a new model is not a problem.

Comment: Check out here for an example: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your `y` values to have both the category and the angle, and write a custom loss function that adds the regression loss and the category loss.

Comment: In that case should I use one set of convolutional and fully connected layers?

Comment: It probably depends. Best to try both and see what works best.